# How to check if value is valid property in Matlab?

Tags: class, user-interface, matlab, properties

Is there a way of checking whether a property value is valid for the given hobject?
I took the 'enable' property below just as an example, my question is for general property, and assuming you don't know all the possible accepted properties values in advance.

```
% MyBtnObject is a standard push button

% this will be ok
set(MyBtnObject, 'enable', 'on');

% and this will not, but how can I check it?
set(MyBtnObject, 'enable', 'SomeInventedProp');
```

Comment: What about using a `try-catch` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer. I can use `x = set(MyBtnObject, 'enable')` to get the possible values to the enable property, listed as cell array `x`.

```
% find buttons
h = findobj('style', 'pushbutton');

% getting all the possible values for 'enable' property for all pushbuttons
% x = set(h, 'enable'), when h is array, will not work
x = arrayfun(@(x)(set(x, 'enable')), h, 'UniformOutput', false);
```