# Put datatip stack on top of axis label and update axes label after a change was done on axes position

Tags: matlab, plot

**This issue is only for unix matlabs, windows users won't be able to reproduce it.**

I am having trouble while trying to create datatips in which are on top of the y axis label. The following picture illustrate the issue:

[image: Issue Example]

As you can see, the datatips created close to the ylabel will get bottom to the ylabel text, **while the desire effect is the opposite: the datatip to be on top of the axis label**.

I generated the plot with the following (not so minimal) code, which is available bellow. You may remove the lines commented with `% may be removed`, or even just put a datatip on −78 instead of a loop in order to achieve a faster testing script, but I leave this code if someone one day wants it to create custom datatips (in this case, consider seeing also http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips/):

```
gradientStep = 1e-1;

x=-100:gradientStep:100; xSize=numel(x);
y=x.^3-x.^2;

figH=figure(42);
lineH=plot(x,y);

ylabel('YLabel (YUnits)','FontSize',16)
xlabel('XLabel (XUnits)','FontSize',16)

dcH=datacursormode(figH);

nTips = 20; % May change the loop for a datatip at x=-78.

for pos = round(linspace(2,xSize,nTips))
  datatipH=dcH.createDatatip(lineH,...
    struct('Position',[x(pos) y(pos)]));

  orientation = 'top-left';

  if pos>1
    tipText{1} = 'The grandient here is: ';
    tipText{2} = ['\Deltax:',sprintf('%d',x(pos)-x(pos-1)),' XUnits'];
    tipText{3} = ['\Deltay:',sprintf('%d',y(pos)-y(pos-1)),' YUnits'];
  else
    tipText = 'Cannot calculate gradient here.';
  end

  bkgColor = [1 1 .5]; % May be removed.
  fontSize = 12; % May be removed.

  set(datatipH,'StringFcn',(@(~,~) tipText),'Orientation',...
    orientation,'backGroundColor',bkgColor,'FontSize',...
    fontSize,'Draggable','on');            % Only set text and orientation needed.    
  datatipTextBoxH=get(datatipH,'TextBoxHandle');  % May be removed.

  uistack(datatipH,'top'); % Unfortunately makes no effect, since the ylabel handles is not at the axes children list

  datatipTextBoxH=get(datatipH,'TextBoxHandle');
  set(datatipTextBoxH,'HorizontalAlignment','left',...
    'VerticalAlignment','top','Margin',0.02,'Interpreter',...
    'tex','FontName','Courier','FontSize',fontSize); % May be removed.

end
uistack(get(gca,'YLabel'),'bottom') % Also makes no effect, for the same reason.
```

I have tried:

- uistack all datatips to top,
- uistack the label to bottom (both of them don't work because the ylabel handle is not in the axes children handles).

---

**Update**: After implementing the @horchler' solution, a new issue appeared: when zooming and panning the axes, the axes label would also move. I've found a small fix for that, I changed the following aspects:

- Set datatip z-value to 1, so that it will always be higher than ylabel axis z.
- Recreating the ylabel afterwards a pan or zoom movement occurs. For this, I implemented `localAxisUpdate` function that get the old ylabel properties, replace it by a new one, and them reset all settable properties but the ylabel position. For this I used this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448161/how-to-check-if-value-is-valid-property-in-matlab)

The resulting code is as follows:

```
function test
  gradientStep = 1e-1;

  x=-100:gradientStep:100; xSize=numel(x);
  y=x.^3-x.^2;

  figH=figure(42);
  lineH=plot(x,y);

  ylabel('YLabel (YUnits)','FontSize',16)
  xlabel('XLabel (XUnits)','FontSize',16)

  dcH=datacursormode(figH);

  %nTips = 20;

  %for pos = round(linspace(2,xSize,nTips))
    pos = find(x>-78,1);
    datatipH=dcH.createDatatip(lineH,...
      struct('Position',[x(pos) y(pos) 1]));

    orientation = 'top-left';

    if pos>1
      tipText{1} = 'The grandient here is: ';
      tipText{2} = ['\Deltax:',sprintf('%d',x(pos)-x(pos-1)),' XUnits'];
      tipText{3} = ['\Deltay:',sprintf('%d',y(pos)-y(pos-1)),' YUnits'];
    else
      tipText = 'Cannot calculate gradient here.';
    end

    bkgColor = [1 1 .5]; % Light Yellow
    fontSize = 12;

    set(datatipH,'StringFcn',(@(~,~) tipText),'Orientation',...
      orientation,'backGroundColor',bkgColor,'FontSize',...
      fontSize,'Draggable','on');
    datatipTextBoxH=get(datatipH,'TextBoxHandle');

    datatipTextBoxH=get(datatipH,'TextBoxHandle');
    set(datatipTextBoxH,'HorizontalAlignment','left',...
      'VerticalAlignment','top','Margin',0.02,'Interpreter',...
  %end

  % Set changes due to zoom and pan to also use adaptativeDateTicks:         
  set(zoom(figH),'ActionPostCallback',...
    @(~,~) localAxisUpdate(gca));
  set(pan(figH),'ActionPostCallback',...
    @(~,~) localAxisUpdate(gca));

end

function localAxisUpdate(aH)    
  % Fix axis label on top of datatip:
  ylh = get(aH,'YLabel');
  % Get original YLabel properties
  ylstruct = get(ylh);
  % Get settable fields:
  yfieldnames=fieldnames(rmfield(set(ylh),'Position'))';
  % Remove old label:
  delete(ylh)
  % Create new one:
  ylh = ylabel(aH,'Dummy');
  % Send it bottom:
  ylpos = get(ylh,'Position');
  set(ylh, 'Position', [ylpos(1:2) 0]);
  % Reset new ylabel to old values:
  for field=yfieldnames
    field = field{1};
    set(ylh,field,ylstruct.(field));
  end
end
```

This approach creates an unwanted effect, which is the ylabel will move across the figure until the mouse button is released. **How can I remove this unwanted effect ?**

I think the solution may be more or less as it was done in [undocummented matlab solution for updating axes ticks](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-axes-tick-labels-format/), but now I would need the listener to the ylabel postset property. Does anyone knows how to do that? If you are a windows user, you can also try to help, **all I need is to reset the position of the ylabel after a change (pan, zoom or whatever) is made on the figure**.

Comment: fyi, you original code works without modification in R2013a (WinXP): http://i.stack.imgur.com/I9MCS.png

Comment: I am using Matlab R2013a also, but on MacOs 10.8.4. Added a request to check if this is really a platform related issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround that uses both [linkaxes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html), so useful when zooming/panning multiple plots, and the visibilty of plots.

1. create an axes (hax_1) with the function to be plotted, without the datatips
2. create an axes (hax_2) with the function to be plotted AND the datatips but without the axes labels
3. set hax_2 visibility to 'off' (this will plot the **datatips above** the first axes labels)
4. link the 2 axes with linkaxes([hax_1 hax_2],'xy'); (zooming and panning on one of the axes will **modify on the fly** the second axes)

This gives with your first code (not the edited one):

```
gradientStep = 1e-1;   
x=-100:gradientStep:100; xSize=numel(x);
y=x.^3-x.^2;   
figH=figure(42);
plot(x,y);   
ylabel('YLabel (YUnits)','FontSize',16)
xlabel('XLabel (XUnits)','FontSize',16)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% modification starts

hax_1 = gca;
hax_2 = axes('Position', get(hax_1,'Position'));
lineH = plot(x,y);
linkaxes([hax_1 hax_2],'xy');
set(hax_2,'Visible', 'off');

% modification ends
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

dcH=datacursormode(figH); 
nTips = 20; % May change the loop for a datatip at x=-78.
for pos = round(linspace(2,xSize,nTips))
  datatipH=dcH.createDatatip(lineH,struct('Position',[x(pos) y(pos)]));
  orientation = 'top-left';
  if pos>1
    tipText{1} = 'The grandient here is: ';
    tipText{2} = ['\Deltax:',sprintf('%d',x(pos)-x(pos-1)),' XUnits'];
    tipText{3} = ['\Deltay:',sprintf('%d',y(pos)-y(pos-1)),' YUnits'];
  else
    tipText = 'Cannot calculate gradient here.';
  end
  bkgColor = [1 1 .5]; % May be removed.
  fontSize = 12; % May be removed.
  set(datatipH,'StringFcn',(@(~,~) tipText),'Orientation',orientation,'backGroundColor',bkgColor,'FontSize',fontSize,'Draggable','on');  % Only set text and orientation needed.    
  datatipTextBoxH=get(datatipH,'TextBoxHandle');
  set(datatipTextBoxH,'HorizontalAlignment','left','VerticalAlignment','top','Margin',0.02,'Interpreter','tex','FontName','Courier','FontSize',fontSize); % May be removed.   
end
```

I am on OSX 10.8.4, R2012b, and had the same issue as yours. Here, the proposed solution plots datatips above the axis labels and allow zooming/panning without making use of undocumented features of matlab.

Comment: Very nice work. An actual "use" for `linkaxes`. So the data tips are being put into an invisible axis that is linked to the main one aligned with  it? I would have though that children of an invisible axis would inherit the invisibility. There are probably other bugs that could be worked around with this technique -though it might be a bit costly in terms of the extra processing/callbacks that are likely required -however that's often not too much of problem for many plots.

Comment: Both axes and plot have a visibility property. In the top layer, only the axes is invisible, the plot and its children -including datatips- remaining visible. I use this trick when a dense representation of data is needed.

Comment: haha wth, I clicked to reward Magla and it rewarded @horchler… very strange… Magla appeared with 15xx reputation, and when I refreshed the page, the bounty went to the answer which I haven't assigned. Sorry for that Magla… anyway, I would like to thank both of you again.

Comment: Hey that's ok - sharing the rewards is fair since horchler answered the initial request.

Answer (score 5):

How about explicitly setting the z-position of the y-label via it's handle? If I put this after your loop it seems to work in R2012b:

```
ylh = get(gca,'Ylabel')
ylpos = get(ylh,'Position');
set(ylh,'Position',[ylpos(1:2) 0]);
```

If I adjust the z-position I can get the y-label to pop up and even interleave between the datatips. I'm not completely sure if this is a bug or a feature, but sometimes there are workarounds to rendering issues that involve tweaking the position of an element slightly to get Matlab to recalculate and redraw the figure.

Comment: Great! Thanks, just what I needed. Couldn't think that the answer would be so simple! I won't close the question for now, just in case someone wants to improve the answer for future "generations".

Comment: Glad that it works for you. I was worried that you might be using a version of Matlab with some bug that would prevent it from working. There are numerous bugs that require just slightly tweaking the position of elements to get Matlab to re-render everything. Leaving it open until the bounty ends or until whenever you like is fine.

Comment: You don't know how happy I am, this was bothering me for so long time. You could add the following phrase to your answer (I didn't know about that), it is very useful: "There are numerous bugs that require just slightly tweaking the position of elements to get Matlab to re-render everything."

Comment: Surprisingly for me his original code already works fine in 2012b.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: I'm also using R2012b on OS X and the original code does not work for me. Are you on Windows per chance? Especially since this is taking advantage of an undocumented feature, I wouldn't be surprised if this is yet another OS X-specific bug.

Comment: On windows indeed, I guess it is safe to say that it is platform dependant as @Werner suspected.

Comment: I've updated the question, the offered solution created another issue. Please let me know if you know how to solve it. Many thanks again!

Comment: @Werner: That's a pretty major change from the original question that did not indicate anything about zooming and panning. It's bordering on a second question -making dynamic plots is a whole other deal and so riddled with issues in my experience that I don't bother. And you're trying to get an undocumented feature to work. I think this new issue stems from setting the label position manually which then breaks all of Matlab's fragile pan/zoom methods that depend on everything being where/how it was when created. Basically, the label reverted to generic text that moves with other plot elements.

Comment: Also, I think that others have faced this issue of moving labels and axis tick labels when creating custom plots. It's a real nightmare. It looks like [this FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16003-tick2text-create-easy-to-customize-tick-labels) overrides the pan and zoom functions with its own versions. No idea how good it is.

Comment: Just read it, it uses the same mechanism that I created on my real program. Just wanted to see if there is a better solution, anyway, it is already solved (thanks to you). And yes, it is quite unfortunate that matlab changes the ylabel to common text…

Comment: @horchler please see my answer that avoids tricking the axes labels. Basically, I put axes on top of each other just like layers in Photoshop. I used this technique for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344915/how-to-add-a-colorbar-and-set-clim-to-a-colour-image-overlaid-on-a-grey-leve/17346892#17346892).